# Facebook Account Kit Redirect into my app

Tags: android, facebook

I have created a facebook accountkit demo, I am doing login with Email, it sends an email on my gmail account. I verify the email link, then I got a link "Open App". I want to redirect on my app after clicking this button, but not able to do so. On clicking "Open App" Button it stays on browser only

I am using the library is below

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
```

for reference please find the image below Attached Image

[attached image][1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE2F5.png

Please let me know how this issue can be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **"Open App"** button has a link, which doesn't work at that point, because your app doesn't handle it.

It looks something like this:

```
ak21************7://authorize/
```

Copy that link and use it in your AndroidManifest.xml to define an intent-filter, so when you click it, your app will start. Like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.DeepLinkActivity" >
    <!-- For Facebook Account Kit -->
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="ak21************7" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Because at login you start the AccountKitActivity for a result, you need to come back to that screen and your registration process will be able to finish, and your onActivityResult will be called.

You can achieve that by defining a blank activity, that automatically closes. That's the same activity that handles the intent filter, mentioned above. The activity looks like this:

```
public class DeepLinkActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        finish();
        return;
    }

}
```

After adding these, the **"Open App"** button worked, it took me back to the app, and my registration process finished